# RxJava2 delay an observable until another observable emits

Tags: observable, delay, rx-java2

This is for unit testing purposes, as I want to verify correct behavior for a function where two data sources may return in different orders. Currently in my unit test, I'm creating an Observable with dummy data and simply using the delay operator to add a delay of 10 milliseconds for the data source I want to return second. However, this seems a bit ugly and could become problematic as I have more and more tests.

Is there a way to have an Observable wait to emit until another Observable completes?

Edit: Here's an example of a unit test that I have

```
public void testNetworkReturningBeforeLocal() {
    Item localItem = new Item("local");
    Item remoteItem = new Item("remote");
    when(mDatabaseMock.getItem(any())).thenReturn(Observable.just(localItem).delay(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    when(mApiMock.getItem(any())).thenReturn(Observable.just(remoteItem));

    TestObserver<Item> observer = new TestObserver<>();
    mRepository.getItem("blah").subscribe(observer); // calls getItem from database and API

    observer.awaitTerminalEvent();
    observer.assertResult(remoteItem);
}
```

I'm using `delay(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)` on the observable returned by the database to simulate the network response arriving first. What I'd like to do is delay the database observable until the network observable completes.

Comment: I would suggest you use a `TestScheduler` and your observables use this scheduler.  You will have to post a minimal test showing what you currently have for a more definitive answer. However it would seem that you can make this easier as all this is just to invoke subsequent behaviour, maybe you are trying to test too much at once - can you not refactor to just test the behaviours independently?

Comment: A couple of ways with operators: `delaySubscription`, `delay(selector)`, `concatEager` to name a few.

Comment: @MarkKeen I've added an example test case above

Comment: @akarnokd none of those seem to work. DelaySubscription delays the subscription but not the emission of items, which is what I need. I'm already using `delay` and want to avoid specifying a specific time to wait. `concatEager` returns one observable, but these are two observables returning test data from two separate sources.

Comment: I'm a little confused, it is quite feasible to assume that a network  call would always be slower than returning a local persisted value? I'm not sure how valid this test is - are you trying to prove rxjava works? That said, for a solution, as stated you'll require a `TestScheduler`, and use that with the delay operator, then forward time by 10 seconds, then make your assertions, also I'd make use `fromCallable` instead of `just` in your mock return values - http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/schedulers/TestScheduler.html you may also find the `amb` operator useful here.

Comment: I think my main concern is that the local database could eventually become quite large, which might make queries on it slower to the point where someone with a fast network connection could conceivably receive the network response first. I will try it out with the test scheduler. What's the benefit of using `fromCallable`?